# Unity 5.9 adds a ton of extra library references

Tags: c#, unity-container

We recently upgraded our solution to use the newly released Unity 5.9.0.

In the process, it looks like Unity added a whole ton of additional library references to each project that it's in. For instance:

```
   <Reference Include="System.AppContext, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.9.0\lib\net47\System.AppContext.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Collections, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.9.0\lib\net47\System.Collections.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.9.0\lib\net47\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.9.0\lib\net47\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.Specialized, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.9.0\lib\net47\System.Collections.Specialized.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.5.9.0\lib\net47\System.ComponentModel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Except there's about 40 or so in total, to each project.

So far as I can tell, it hasn't had any negative repercussions so far, but I certainly don't want all these references in each project if we don't need them.

Is this actually necessary? Or is it a bug in the new 5.9 (in the nuget configuration, maybe?) that's going to need to get fixed?

Comment: Are you familiar with .NET Standard and .NET Core? You shouldn't be surprised if you are

Comment: You can remove references using the Solution Explorer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Quite honestly, no, I don't have a very good mental model for how those two technologies fit into existing .NET 4.7 projects. Mostly what I've been able to pick up about them is that they make certain impossible things possible, and lots of simple things much more complicated. If this is just one of those simple things that they made complicated, I can deal with it. Just wanting to make sure.

Comment: @jdweng - Right, but (a) do I need to, and (b) will the references all come back the next time Unity publishes a point release, and (c) if I do (or if I don't!), will I run into strange, bizarre, unexplained and apparently unrelated assembly binding issues six months from now?

Comment: This is one of those simple things made difficult. All the libraries used to be part of the .NET Framework, so you didn't see them as references

Comment: Nothing bad should happen if you delete all of those, the GAC will provide them for you from your local .NET installation, although the MAY come back with an update, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, when I upgraded to Unity 5.9.3, it removed all those extra references. So my assumption is that this was a bug in Unity 5.9.0 through 5.9.2.